# Downloaded images/music files not appearing

Tags: downloading, gallery, lg-g2

I've been having problems with my gallery and music app on my lg g2. 
I recently initiated a factory-rest on my phone and I wanted to download an image to see if it would work appropriately, but it refuses to create a "Download" folder and put it in there.  They still download and I can open them manually by tapping on them, but the gallery itself doesn't create a folder to place it in. I poked around on my computer with the usb connection with my charger, and I don't see anything wrong.  Something notable though, is I did delete the .nomedia folder before I factory-reset, but it appears to have returned.  The files even show up in the folder, but they're not able to be viewed by the gallery app. I'm using the default one that came with the phone, and I have tried many solutions, but to no avail.  If there's a solution anyone can recommend to me, it would be very much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is common "bug", I would like to call, they will appear as soon as the mobile is restarted and files are registered in Media library.

Another trick I use is I copy that downloaded folder to another folder using a file manager, and voila. You should try it too.